# What type of probability distribution is this?

Tags: probability-distributions

This is probably a simple question, but I would like to check what kind of distribution is this? Is there a name for such distributions?

$\Pr(X=k)=0.4−0.1k$, $k=0,1,2,3$

Comment: Linear?  Not sure I've ever heard that term used in this context before but it would seem to fit.

Comment: yeah. I've never heard of the term used in this context either. I'm trying to figure out the properties of the distribution and stuff

Comment: Well, of course there are lots and lots of distributions...the named ones get special attention either because they model standard situations or because they are analytically tractable (or both).  Polynomial distributions, like this one, are easy enough to work with.  Not clear to me what situations they model, but I expect there are some.